# verdaccio install successfully, but the package was only downloaded to verdaccio's storage

Tags: node.js, npm, verdaccio

I used "npm install npmtest" command to download my test private package. But there was no package downloaded in my project directory. After that, I used "npm install jquery" to download jquery plugin, but the plugin was only downloaded to verdaccio's storage too, there was not jquery plugin in my project directory.

### verdaccio config file

```
storage: ./storage
plugins: ./plugins

web:
  title: Verdaccio

auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd

uplinks:
  cnpmjs:
    url: https://registry.npm.taobao.org/

packages:
  '@*/*':
    # scoped packages
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    proxy: cnpmjs

  '**':
    access: $all

    publish: $authenticated

    proxy: cnpmjs

middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true

logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
```

### Info after executing npm install

[image]

The test2 directory was still empty. Can anyone tell me why is that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The output doesn't indicate where in the filesystem your `test2` directory is, but the log messages show that the working directory for npm was `/Users/lc/Documents/study`, so the most likely reason that test2 is empty is that it is a subdirectory of `study` and `study` has a `.npmrc` or something else that caused npm to detect that as being the root of the project, so the file you are looking for ended up in `/Users/lc/Documents/study/node_modules/jquery`.